# How can I send a Python program (including libraries) to a friend?

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I want to send a program that I made to my friend, but the problem is it's not going to work on his computer, because he doesn't have all the libraries installed.
For example :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import sys
```

how can I send him all necessary libraries?
hope my question is clear.

Comment: Is your friend a developer and you want to make sure he can get all the libraries/packages easily, or do you just want him to run your application?

Comment: he is a developer, and he needs an actual code.

Comment: The standard way is to use `virtualenv`, install your packages locally with `pip`, make sure it runs, then use `pip freeze` to generate a requirements file

Comment: Take a look at http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also try "Python to EXE":

```
http://www.py2exe.org/
```

This packs up a script & it components into an package that runs with an included exe.

If you are brave, you can "roll your own", gathering up the key DLL's and EXE for python:

```
.\MSVCR71.dll
.\OCI.dll
.\python.exe
.\python25.dll
```

And all the needed *.pyc & *.pyd files in Python HOME's Lib directory:

```
.\Lib\cx_Oracle.pyc
.\Lib\cx_Oracle.pyd
.\Lib\encodings\aliases.pyc
.\Lib\glob.pyc
.\Lib\logging\config.pyc
.\Lib\os.pyc
.\Lib\pprint.pyc
... excreta ...
```

Taking all the files and any of your developed *.py scripts and rolling them up into an appropriate
directory structure and zipping it up for distribution.